# Having trouble with if statement containing string

Tags: java, string, comparison, charat

I am having trouble trying to compare a string using charAt()  for some reason it throws a fit when trying to compare it to "1".  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
public static void nthDigitTally1(int n, int num, int tally[]){
    String numString = Integer.toString(num);

    System.out.println(numString);
    System.out.println(numString.charAt(2));


    for(int i = 0; i < countDigits(num); i++){
        if(numString.charAt(i) == "1"){
            System.out.println("It works cappin");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `countDigits(num)` use `numString.length()`

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a `char` with a `String`; don't do that.

`numString.charAt(i) == "1"` should be `numString.charAt(i) == '1'`

A `char` should be represented with single quotes (`'`) and `String`s with doubles (`"`). In addition, `String`s should not be compared with `==` but [`String#equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
  if(numString.charAt(i) == "1"){
```

With:

```
   if(numString.charAt(i) == '1'){
```

Because `""` for string and `''` for char